# Animal jumping equally likely to the left and right.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability

We have an animal that starts at the point zero and jumps equally likely to the left(-1) and right(+1). After 2k jumps, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ ,it arrives back again at the point $0$. The question is: How likely is it that during this process, the animal was never in the negative area?

Comment: Perhaps the following logic would help: After $1$ jump, the probability is just $\dfrac{1}{2}$ for going to the right *only*. After $2$ jumps, the probability is $\dfrac{1}{2}$, as the animal is in $+1$, and so going to the left would give $0$, which is nonnegative. Continue on to get the desired probability.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number
see if you can make a connection between your problem and (for example) the parenthesis interpretation